# Maven Release-plugin "tag already exists" for nonexistant tag

Tags: git, maven, bamboo, bitbucket-server, svn2git

My setup: `git`-repository on an `Atlassian Stash`-server and `Atlassian Bamboo`.
I'm using `Maven 3.1.1` with the `release-plugin 2.3.2`. The plan in `Bamboo` looks like this:

1. Check out from `git`-repository
2. perform a `clean install`
3. perform `release:prepare` and `release:perform` with `ignoreSnapshots=true` and `resume=false`

Everything up to the last step works fine, but `Maven` states, that it can't tag the release, because the tag already exists. Here is the log:

```
build   26-Nov-2013 10:36:37    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project [PROJECT-NAME]: Unable to tag SCM
build   26-Nov-2013 10:36:37    [ERROR] Provider message:
build   26-Nov-2013 10:36:37    [ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
build   26-Nov-2013 10:36:37    [ERROR] Command output:
build   26-Nov-2013 10:36:37    [ERROR] fatal: tag '[PROJECT-NAME]-6.2.2' already exists
```

Well, obviously the tag already exists, no big deal. However, this is what `git tag` looks like for my repository:

```
bash:~/git/repositories/PROJECT-NAME$ git tag
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.2.5
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.3.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.3.1
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.4.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.5.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.5.1
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.5.2
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.5.3
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.5.4
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.1
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.2
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.3
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.4
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.5
[PROJECT-NAME]-5.6.6
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.0.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.0.1
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.0.2
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.1.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.1.1
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.1.2
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.2.0
[PROJECT-NAME]-6.2.1
```

The `git`-repository is cloned via `svn2git` from an `svn`-repository. I've tried multiple times reimporting the repository and deleting and re-cloning it on the `stash`-server. Yet the tag `6.2.2` seems to exist somewhere in the depths for `Maven`. What's going on here?

Update: I just tried removing ALL tags from the repository. Same result. Changing the version from `6.2.2` to `6.2.3` showed positive results.

Another update: It seems to have something to do with the name of the repository. Creating a new repository with the same name but adding `-2` at the end helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after my last discovery which screamed "CACHE PROBLEM!" I found the solution. I deleted all repository-cache-data following the instructions on this site: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMKB/Git+cache+removal+in+Bamboo

Comment: Do you know how to do this if the build tool is Jenkins?

Answer (score 10):

`mvn release:clean` before `release:prepare` is what worked for me

Comment: I have jenkins job setup and it already has these commands in the script which is supposed to build jars. The build is successful but the job fails with this error none the less.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this error again and again in a Jenkins release build after a release had failed previously. I restored the repository state before the release and verified that the tag did not exist anymore using `git tag`. To be absolutely sure, I also deleted the tag locally and remotely using:

```
git tag --delete mytag
git push --delete origin mytag
```

Both commands reported that the tag did not exist. Regardless, the release build kept failing with

```
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: tag 'mytag' already exists`.
```

I finally solved this by enabling the option

```
Build Environment -> Delete workspace before build starts
```

Hence the problem is that after a failed release build the Jenkins workspace is left with a dirty repository state in which the tag still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try options "Clean before Build" and "Clean After Build" within Source Code Management -> Additional Behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was running `mvn clean` .